# How to create REST API in magento 1.9?

Tags: rest, magento, magento-1.9

How to create API in REST magento. How to create role and user in `magento 1.9`  ?

Is there any demo available for above?

Comment: Did you have a look at the [development document site](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html)? Adjust your question and ask just one specific question.

Comment: But it is not how to implement custom API endpoint in Magento.